# add reset function to click counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

This works, but the problem is it works only one time -- and then class `('active')` is never added again -- it needs to be removed after 5 clicks as as done with the below, but after 5 it needs to reset and I would like the counter to go back to `0` so that after another 5 clicks it could work again!

```
var clickCount = 0;

$(".arrowRight").click(function () {
    clickCount++;

    if (clickCount >= 5)
        // alert ("stop it!");
    $(".arrowRight").removeClass("active"); 
    else { 
    $(".arrowRight").addClass("active"); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just set clickCount back to 0 when you remove the class?

Comment: You have 2.5k rep and yet you cant see that `clickCount` will always stay above 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will something like this work?

```
var clickCount = 0;

$(".arrowRight").click(function () {
    clickCount++;

    if (clickCount >= 5) {
        clickCount = 0;
        $(".arrowRight").removeClass("active");
    }
    else { 
        $(".arrowRight").addClass("active"); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

just set `clickCount = 0` in the if statement

```
if (clickCount >= 5)
  clickCount = 0;
  $(".arrowRight").removeClass("active"); 
else { 
  $(".arrowRight").addClass("active"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another option:

```
if (clickCount%5==0) {
$(".arrowRight").removeClass("active");
} else {
$(".arrowRight").addClass("active");
}
```